# How many pairs of digits A,B such that ABA+BAB is divisible by 74?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

ABA and BAB are not multiplication, they just denote digits.

I realized that ABA plus BAB will result in the last 3 digits being repeated, so do I find all multiple of 74 that have 3 repeating digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABA+BAB=111A+111B=111(A+B)=3x37(A+B) 
which divides 74 when A+B is even

### where A,B is an element of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

so 
(A,B)=(1,1) (1,3) (1,5) (1,7) (1,9) (3,...) (5,...) (7,...) (9,...)
so there are 25 pairs where both A and B are odd

There is also (2,2) (2,4) (2,6) (2,8) (4,..) (6,..) (8,..)
which is another 16 solutions

Total =41 pairs

Comment: Are we supposed to count ordered pairs, or unordered ones?

Comment: We are supposed to count the pairs I'd say A=1 B=3 is a different pair to A=3 B=1

Answer (score 2):

Render the sum as $111\times(a+b)=3 \times 37\times (a+b)$.  What property must the factor $a+b$ have to complete divisibility by $2\times 37=74$?  Once you know this it is easy to count the favored pairs.